# IP address in different range continues to communicate

Tags: wireless-networking, ip-address

This has probably been asked before, but I can't seem to find the specific circumstance.

I was configuring a D-Link access point for a friend, testing it on my network giving it a fixed IP of 192.168.1.50.  When finished with the setup, I changed its fixed IP address to 10.0.0.50 to match my friend's network. Both use the subnet 255.255.255.0.

I was surprised to find the unit remained functional with an IP address of 10.0.0.50 that didn't match my network 192.168.1.x. I could select the D-Link on my wifi only iPad and have internet communication. Oddly, the unit did not show up on my AT&T U-verse router with either address.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An access point is mostly a Layer 2 device, it simply bridges traffic between Ethernet and Wi-Fi, much like a switch works with Ethernet.

The only things Layer 3 it does is getting the time (probably) and its admin interface.

It does not appear on your router because its network settings do not match your network. It tries to communicate with a router inside `10.0.0.0/24`, which is not reachable.